# Logstash Docker Compose simplest stdin input and standard output example

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, docker-compose, logstash

I am trying to create a simplest example of Logstash on Docker Compose which will take input from stdin and give output to standard out. It's not working as expected. The following are the config files

### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  logstash-sandbox:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.8.0
    container_name: logstash-sandbox
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
      - ./conf:/var/logstash/configuration
    ports:
      - 9600:9600
      - 5044:5044
    networks:
      - host

networks:
  host:
```

### logstash.yml

```yaml
http.host: 0.0.0.0
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
xpack.management.enabled: false

config.reload.automatic: true
config.reload.interval: 6s

log.level: info
log.format: json

path.config: /var/logstash/configuration/*.conf
```

### filter in conf folder

```
input { stdin { } }

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
      stdout {}
}
```

### Logs

```sh
$ docker-compose up  
Creating network "agents_host" with the default driver
WARNING: Found orphan containers (filebeat-sandbox, kibana-sandbox, es01-sandbox) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Creating logstash-sandbox ... done
Attaching to logstash-sandbox
logstash-sandbox    | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
logstash-sandbox    | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
logstash-sandbox    | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules (file:/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/jruby-complete-9.2.11.1.jar) to method sun.nio.ch.NativeThread.signal(long)
logstash-sandbox    | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules
logstash-sandbox    | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
logstash-sandbox    | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
logstash-sandbox    | Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
logstash-sandbox    | {"level":"INFO","loggerName":"logstash.setting.writabledirectory","timeMillis":1594296137893,"thread":"main","logEvent":{"message":"Creating directory","setting":"path.queue","path":"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}}
logstash-sandbox    | {"level":"INFO","loggerName":"logstash.setting.writabledirectory","timeMillis":1594296137959,"thread":"main","logEvent":{"message":"Creating directory","setting":"path.dead_letter_queue","path":"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}}
logstash-sandbox    | {"level":"WARN","loggerName":"logstash.config.source.multilocal","timeMillis":1594296138392,"thread":"LogStash::Runner","logEvent":{"message":"Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified"}}
logstash-sandbox    | {"level":"INFO","loggerName":"logstash.runner","timeMillis":1594296138398,"thread":"LogStash::Runner","logEvent":{"message":"Starting Logstash","logstash.version":"7.8.0","jruby.version":"jruby 9.2.11.1 (2.5.7) 2020-03-25 b1f55b1a40 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.7+10-LTS on 11.0.7+10-LTS +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}}
logstash-sandbox    | {"level":"INFO","loggerName":"logstash.agent","timeMillis":1594296138432,"thread":"LogStash::Runner","logEvent":{"message":"No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID","uuid":"a7b0afbc-b2ab-4019-8a23-a771ae0513d5","path":"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}}
logstash-sandbox    | {"level":"INFO","loggerName":"org.reflections.Reflections","timeMillis":1594296140309,"thread":"Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>","logEvent":{"message":"Reflections took 44 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 21 keys and 41 values "}}
logstash-sandbox    | {"level":"INFO","loggerName":"logstash.javapipeline","timeMillis":1594296141109,"thread":"[main]-pipeline-manager","logEvent":{"message":"Starting pipeline","pipeline_id":"main","pipeline.workers":8,"pipeline.batch.size":125,"pipeline.batch.delay":50,"pipeline.max_inflight":1000,"pipeline.sources":["/var/logstash/configuration/kong-filter.conf"],"thread":"#<Thread:0x8104977 run>"}}
logstash-sandbox    | {"level":"INFO","loggerName":"logstash.javapipeline","timeMillis":1594296142209,"thread":"[main]-pipeline-manager","logEvent":{"message":"Pipeline started","pipeline.id":"main"}}
logstash-sandbox    | {"level":"INFO","loggerName":"logstash.agent","timeMillis":1594296142311,"thread":"Agent thread","logEvent":{"message":"Pipelines running","count":1,"running_pipelines":[{"metaClass":{"metaClass":{"metaClass":{"running_pipelines":"[:main]","non_running_pipelines":[]}}}}]}}
logstash-sandbox    | {"level":"INFO","loggerName":"logstash.agent","timeMillis":1594296142656,"thread":"Api Webserver","logEvent":{"message":"Successfully started Logstash API endpoint","port":9600}}




127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013:00:01:45 -0800] "GET /xampp/status.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3891 "http://cadenza/xampp/navi.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
```

I do not get any output as expected.

Comment: Have you tried to open another terminal and take a look on `docker logs logstash-sandbox -f`?

Comment: @Tarasovych , its not running in daemon mode( the docker-compose command does not have -d option), so it will give the same result as we see here. I have verified, it gives me same reault.

Comment: You don't appear to set up any input to your logstash instance? So of course there is no output. Or maybe that is as expected, if I have misunderstood your last sentence, and you are after something else?